# Dark/ light color of up/down vote arrows

Tags: support, voting, design

I noted that some arrows are darker than others. Could there be a problem in my computer?

Answer (score 4):

You mean like this? The up arrow is black, the down arrow is gray?

[image]

Hover over the arrow, and it'll show (a bit cryptically) that you already have voted on the post:

[image]